# E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout. No data is displayed

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I am trying to fetch data from firebase and put it into a recycler view through adapter. But, no data is being displayed.
My code in Main Activity:

```
 DatabaseReference databaseReference;
RecyclerView recyclerView;
ArrayList<Menu> menuList;
EditMenuAdapter editMenuAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit_menu);

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    menuList = new ArrayList<Menu>();

    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("menu");

    databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                Menu menu = dataSnapshot1.getValue(Menu.class);
                menuList.add(menu);

            }

            editMenuAdapter = new EditMenuAdapter(EditMenuActivity.this, menuList);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(editMenuAdapter);

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            Toast.makeText(EditMenuActivity.this, "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });
```

My adapter class:

```
public class EditMenuAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<EditMenuAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

Context context;
ArrayList<Menu> menuArrayList;

public EditMenuAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<Menu> menus) {

    context = c;
    menuArrayList = menus;

}

@NonNull
@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    return new MyViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.menu_list_layout, parent, false));
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

    holder.dishNameTextView.setText(menuArrayList.get(position).getDishName());
    holder.dishPriceTextView.setText(menuArrayList.get(position).getDishPrice());

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return menuArrayList.size();
}

class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView dishNameTextView;
    TextView dishPriceTextView;
    Switch dishActiveSwitch;

    public MyViewHolder(View view) {

        super(view);

        dishNameTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.dishNameTextView);
        dishPriceTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.dishPriceTextView);
        dishActiveSwitch = (Switch) view.findViewById(R.id.dishActiveSwitch);

    }

}
```

}

The layout resource file is:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".EditMenuActivity">

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:layout_width="397dp"
    android:layout_height="599dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/doneButton"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:text="Done"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/recyclerView" />
```

The log shows: E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout. No data is displayed.

Only the switch is being displayed on the screen. Please help!

Comment: The message is just telling you that a RecyclerView was told to render itself before you set an adapter on it.  I'm confused because the layout you show doesn't even have a RecyclerView in it.  And we can't know why it's not showing data, because you haven't indicated what it should be showing.  Please edit the question to be more clear what you expect to happen instead, and what you've done to debug this.

Comment: My bad! I put the layout resource file. I changed it now.

Comment: You can set adapter in onCreate and then call notifyDatasetChanged() when the data in the list is changed.

Comment: ok so.. the error is gone now.. but I'm still not able to see any data.. It should fetch the data from firebase and setText to the text views in the layout file.. but its not happening!

Answer (score 2):

Create instance of adapter in `onCreate` and attach it to RV:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  ...
  editMenuAdapter = new EditMenuAdapter(this, new ArrayList<>());
  recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
  ...
}
```

In the response of Firebase `onDataChange`:

```
public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
  ...
  editMenuAdapter.setItems(menuList);
  runOnUiThread(() -> editMenuAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged());
}
```

Comment: Alternatively, add a single argument constructor for `EditMenuAdapter` that shows a [Throbber](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Throbber) while you wait for data.

Comment: ok so.. the error is gone now.. but I'm still not able to see any data..
It should fetch the data from firebase and setText to the text views in the layout file.. but its not happening!

Comment: if you have added notifyDatasetChanged() try putting your response in logcat and see if you are getting proper response